# Entity framework navigation property - duplicates created

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my simpllifed domain model:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
     public abstract IEnumerable<AbstractClass> Children { get; }
}

public abstract class Project : AbstractClass
{
    List<Document> Documents {get;set;}
    public override IEnumerable<AbstractClass> Children
    {
        get { return this.Documents; }
    }
}

public abstract class Document : AbstractClass
{
    //misc
}
```

I recently added the above abstract "Children" property and the assocated override in the Project class.  This was done because I need a reference to "Children" for user interface purposes (other classes inheriting from AbstractClass also will have Children navigation property).

The problem is that, now, when I retrieve the graph of Projects/Documents, duplicate documents are shown in the object graph.  I'm thinking I need some sort of clone method here, but speed is important and I just wanted to reference the existing Documents navigation property rather than cloning the object.

I think there is a simple solution to this but it escapes me.

Thanks.

Edit:

For clarity, I am retrieving the data from a SQL database via a Web Api and the problem occurs after the Web Api send the result message back to the client.  So it looks like the Children property may be causing the problem perhaps at the deserialization stage.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the database table?

Comment: No duplicates in the database table.  The problem only occurred after adding the "Children" abstract property.

Comment: I assume this is code-first? Try to mark the `Children` properties as `[NotMapped]`.

Comment: Yes, its code first and I tried [NotMapped] initially on the concrete Documents class and now on the abstract class and it doesn't change the result.  I think this doesn't work because the NotMapped affects what tracks to the database and the retrieval is fine from the database.  The problem only arises after a successful retrieval.

Comment: Note that I just updated the question to clarify my last comment because I believe this may narrow down the possibilitiies.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may come to this page, I solved this problem by using an abstract method vs. a property in the AbstractClass, ie.

```
public abstract IEnumerable<AbstractClass> GetKeyChildren();
```

I'm still not clear on why the duplicates occurred.